# header row in knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js

I want to have some HTML like the following:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: foo">
            <td>some header</td>
            <td data-bind="value: bar"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want repeated cells generated by a Knockout `foreach` binding.  But how can I do this while having a header cell which I don't want repeated?  The desired output, after binding, is something like:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>some header</td>
            <td>fred</td>
            <td>wilma</td>
            <td>barney</td>
            <td>bam-bam</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The same question applies to having a header row.  If the `foreach` binding is on the `<tr>` element, how do I tell Knockout not to repeat the first row or cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the containerless version of the binding ( see in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html): Using foreach without a container element section)

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>some header</td>
            <!-- ko foreach: foo -->
                <td data-bind="text: bar"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8qjy/).

So the same technique can be used if you want to have a fixed header row:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>some header</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: foo -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: bar"></td>
            </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Some header</td>
            <!-- ko foreach: foo -->
            <td data-bind="value: bar"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To repeat `tr` you can use same desicion, but it better to use html possibilities

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> Header </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: foo">
            <td data-bind="text: bar"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```